# Sense2vec : os error Could not open binary file b

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, sense2vec

after installing sense2vec when i try to load the reddit_vector file using

import sense2vec
model=sense2vec.load(r"C:\Users\Leanda\Downloads\reddit_vectors-1.1.0 second")

it gives me this error:

OSError: Could not open binary file b'C:\Users\Leanda\Downloads\reddit_vectors-1.1.0 second\vectors.bin'

Comment: I was having the same error. I Installed the latest version of sense2vec rather than 1.0.0a0 as mentioned in the spacy.io doc. Also downloaded the pre-trained vectors from [this link](https://pypi.org/project/sense2vec/#pretrained-vectors) After extracting, point straight to the directory having the `vectors` file instead of the root directory to whatever was extracted. Also better remove any pre-existing spacy version, I used a separate conda environment for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of the models from a previous install you can place it in a folder and load them with :

```
from sense2vec.vectors import VectorMap
vector_map = VectorMap(128)
vector_map.load('/your/folder/reddit_vectors-1.1.0/')
```

Comment: i dont have a copy of the model from previous install as i just started using sense2vec recently have  downloaded the latest updated model  file (raddit_vector) is there no way i can load it or can you provide me the file

Comment: ```pip install sense2vec==1.0.0a0``` You can download sense2vec via pip by specifying the exact version. source [link](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec/releases)

Comment: but i get an error for that command                                                             
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iuaccbug\sense2vec\

Comment: it will be nice if you could provide  me with the older model    thank you for you response

Comment: This is the [link](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/4a/a1d9a28545adc839789c1442e7314cb0c70b8657a885f9e5b287fade7814/sense2vec-1.0.0a0.tar.gz).

Comment: and i just have to load it inplace  of the reddit_vector file

Comment: i get this even if i download the model that you send me      from sense2vec.vectors import VectorMap
vector_map = VectorMap(128)
vector_map.load(file path )         error =SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape   , if i put an r before the path     vector_map.load(r"C:\Users\Leanda\Downloads\sense2vec-1.0.0a0 (2)")      i get this error =ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sense2vec.vectors'    please help me

Comment: please send me snapshot of cmd.

Comment: Here is the error link -https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXkGS9YkG2DoCBJuBDRWgDgq79_yldpG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i am using jupyternotebook

Comment: try run on normal python script not on notebook or python shell.